# tshark : in a HTTP POST request how get form datas in a pretty output?

Tags: debian, wireshark, tshark

I'm a teacher and I want to simulate with my students a MITM attack. The goal is to show why the http**s** protocol must be always used.

On debian, I installed tshark. All works fine, when I run the hotspot mode and run tshark, I can get HTTP packets and, digging a little, we can see the form datas in plain text :

[image]

First, from the browser in the computer 10.42.0.21, when I enter the url of the server (a simple GET request) tshark shows the get request twice. I don't understand why.. is there a way for delete deplicate or find the reason ? (the server log show two GET requests)

secondly, when I send a POST request to the server (via a simple html form). We can see in plain text the datas of the form (it's logic because the server uses the HTTP protocole and not the HTTP**S**)

The curent output is : `Timestamp,POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n,\r\n,Form item : "fname" = "John"`

Is it possible with tshark to get a more prettiest output containing only the items (fields) values of the form ? like this : `"fname" = "John"`

Thanks for any help :)

**EDIT** : for the duplicate, this is because of a favicon request, the issue is from my python server, not from tshark.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `grep` command to search for lines containing form items, then split out the relevant data you want with the `cut` command.

In your example something like `tshark | grep "Form item" | cut -d":" -f2` would probably do what you want.

Comment: thx you for your help and indeed you're right ! a simple pipe/grep can be sufficient... However, when I try it (with your example) I get a number in output, this is strange... screenshot here : https://i.ibb.co/31NQ4tn/IMG-20201231-213311735.jpg